# How to properly access an SQL DB from Android securely

Tags: java, android, authentication

I'm in in process of looking to create an `Android app`; security is obviously the most important thing to keep in mind.

What is the *best-practice* for authenticating a user and handling business logic (scenario below).

For example, the current design would facilitate the permissions based on the user's login. When a user logs in and successfully authenticates, their Username and Password are stored in session variables. When the user attempts to request a resource that requires a certain permission to view, as part of the process for accessing the resource their Username and Password is sent up to the intermediary Web Service, if this authenticates with the correct permission-set the resource is then accessible.

Is this a reasonable way of operating an Android application or is there a better solution to handling this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably you're referring to building some sort of web API such as REST API that the Android App would send requests to and the API performs the database actions.

I wouldn't send the username/password combo for every request that tends to be bad practice. You send the user/password combo once to authenticate and the authentication returns some sort of token and this token is then sent in every request and is validated on the API side to ensure it is a valid session token. You could either roll this yourself or use some sort of Single Sign On (SSO) solution such as Google Sign on for example or OAUTH is a common authentication mechanism. Maybe https://oauth.net/ will help.

Comment: So would this token we generate be bound to the user in some table in the DB for example so we can relate it to a specific user?

Comment: It depends on the implementation. For example if the API was PHP when you call session_start the browser gets a cookie called PHPSESSID by default (it can be renamed I believe) (the same as on Android depending on which HTTP client you use) and then for every subsequent request the cookie is passed back to the ID and uses the same session. That's not something I could give an answer to really as it heavily depends on what backend your using and the implementation. There are a lot of authentication systems available such as firebase that look after that for you so that might be a simpler option